# ActiveRecord::JDBCError: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'content' at row 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

If I post a message with 84kb throw an error data too long.
'content' column data-type is text.
In rails3 its working fine but not in rails4.

Tried in following ways still getting 
- I had tried strict: false in database.yml file.

- sql_mode: default
- variables:
  strict_mode: false
- variables:
  sql_mode: 'traditional'
- tried editing a gem 'sprockets-strict-mode'.